# Building phonegap app plugin error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I created a zip package from my app.

Then, I uploaded it to phonegap build to create the apk file I need.

In the output, I saw this:

> **Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation" via npm Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "4.0.1" for android Plugin doesn't
>   support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android:
>   6.2.3, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0 Skipping 'cordova-plugin-geolocation' for android Fetching plugin**
>
> "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" via npm Installing
>
> "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" at "2.0.2" for android Fetching plugin
>
> "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" via npm Installing
>
> "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" at "5.0.2" for android Fetching plugin
>
> "cordova-plugin-whitelist" via npm Installing
>
> "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.3.3" for android version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be
>   built in. Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" via npm
>
> Installing "cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" at "1.1.0" for android
>
> Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" via npm Installing
>
> "cordova-plugin-statusbar" at "2.4.1" for android Fetching plugin
>
> "phonegap-plugin-push@2.0.0" via npm Installing "phonegap-plugin-push"
>
> at "2.0.0" for android Subproject Path: CordovaLib Fetching plugin
>
> "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" via npm Installing
>   "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" at "7.0.2" for android Plugin doesn't
>   support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android:
>   6.2.3, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0 Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner' for android**

This is my confing.xml:

```
<widget id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="info@aaa.com" href="http://www.aaa.com/">aaaa</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.0.0" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />

</widget>
```

I tried to add the last line to specify the android engine, but the output is the same. I'm using the phonegap version 7.0.1 and I prefer to keep it. Is there a way to reach my goal, keeping this phonegap version and adding the plugins I need [gps reader and barcode scanner]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.1" />
```

and for Barcode use this plugin

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner.git" source="git" >
    <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To scan barcodes." />
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Good, it built the apk... can you please explain me your code, especially the part for the barcode scanner?

Comment: Actually after updating phonegap cli 7+.Few plugins are not supporting like barcode geolocation etc.So making it workable i used specific versions of plugins.